# I want to implement bandpass filter to remove noisy frequencies and then find the peak frequency

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to filter the frequencies and then find the peak frequencies. But I am getting irrelevant values which are not in the frequency range. I don't know where am I going wrong.
[Link to the project](https://github.com/iamvinitk/AudioQr/blob/master/decode.py)

```
w = np.fft.fft(data)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(w))
print(freqs.min(), freqs.max())
# (-0.5, 0.499975)



# I want to implement a bandpass filter here and I have tried this

'''
iw = butter_bandpass_filter(w, low_cut, high_cut, sample_rate, order=10)
w = np.fft.ifft(iw)
'''


# Find the peak in the coefficients
idx = np.argmax(np.abs(w))
freq = freqs[idx]
freq_in_hertz = abs(freq * frate)
print(freq_in_hertz)
# 439.8975
```

Comment: Please mention what you expect and what you got, it's very unclear as to what you are trying to achieve as opposed to what you have got. Please elaborate the question

Comment: I am recording audio using `PyAudio` and want to remove any frequency less than 14kHz and then find the dominant frequency from the filtered frequency. I have added a link to the code in question. @GeneX